# Storing Regular Expressions in a DataTable - C#

Tags: c#, regex

I currently have some code that compares a string to a list of regular expressions that are stored in a text file. I am now trying to move those regex's to a Database, so I thought I might try and have the Database then copy into a DataTable so I could then do it similarly but currently it is failing to match them.

```
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Regex FROM dbo.Regex","ConnectionString"))
        {
            da.Fill(data);
        }
        foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
        {
            String rowAsString = row.ToString();
            var reg = new Regex(rowAsString);
            if (reg.IsMatch(text))
            {              
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `row.ToString()` will return you full name of `DataRow` class. Try to get regex value like this:

```
var regexString = row["Regex"] as string;
var regex = new Regex(regexString);
```

Comment: Yep. `row["Regex"] as string` or `row[0] as string` both should work.